# Verify JWT Token error 'secretOrPrivateKey must have a value'

Tags: jwt, token

return failure(new Error('secretOrPrivateKey must have a value'));[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvTjN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your application is not able to read the environnement variables.

I advice you to use the package `dotenv` : https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

After installing it you have to import it at the top of your application like this:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
```

Specify a file `.env` at the root of your application and add your variables

```js
JWT_SECRET=12bob12ou2b1ob
NODE_ENV=development
```

After, you can use the variables like you did in your linked image:

```js
const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
```